# Show content only in printing page not in browser page using CSS or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I am having some dynamic content that should be shown only in the printing page and not in the web page using CSS or javascript.
Please help me to do this.

For example;

I am having a div content like this..

```
echo '<div id="noshow">'.$val.'</div>'; //i am using php and $val is a dynamic value.
```

I need to show this value only in the printing page and not in the browser page. I used `display:none`. But, I don't know how to make it to display again in the printing page.

Comment: Put your print-specific styles in `@media print { #noshow { display: none; } }`.

Comment: Take a look to this http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: Do you have two sets of CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you're regular stylesheet you could use @media queries for your print css...

```
@media print {
    #hid { display: table-row; }
}
```

or you could add a print style.css to the head of your page with the `media` attribute.

```
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
</head>
```

Comment: It works..but, i am having a table's tr as hidden.. While displaying it in print shows this as a block not as a table's tr.. help me..

Comment: say for ex, this is my code `<style>
@media print {
 #hid
 {
  display:block;
 }
 }
#hid
{
 display:none;
}
</style>
<?php
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>Bye</td></tr>';
echo '<tr id="hid"><td>hai</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
?>` It hides the hai in both printing view and browser view.. Help me.

Comment: i tried all most all property values in this link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp still doesn't work.

Comment: for a tr you should show it as a table row. I've updated my answer with the correct display property for you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have two sets of CSS. One that is specifically around displaying to the browser and one that is for printing.

Look in to http://printstylesheet.dbushell.com/

Cheers
Truez

Comment: Pasting a link is not an answer. Answer a question with example code.

Comment: Aaron, Correct it's not but the answer isn't to just gift the user the answer. One answer is too use two sets of CSS one for printing and one for normal display, the URL just shows a case where the user has hidden any elements within the body section.